# Convergent iff lim-inf=lim-sup

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence.
Then $(x_n)$ converges iff $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n$

I try to prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction first. Then I realize I have to prove $|\sup\limits_{k\ge n} x_k-x_n|\lt\epsilon$

I try to assume $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}x_k-x_n\ge\epsilon$, how can I show the contradiction?

Thank you!

Comment: The sequence $(\sup_{k\ge n} x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic and decreases, conversely $(\inf_{k\ge n} x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic and increases.

Comment: Your sequence indices are incorrect, it should be $x_k$.

Answer (score 1):

A proof using context of subsequence for your reference:

($\Leftarrow$)Let $x_{n_k}$ be a  convergent subsequence of $x_n$, then
$$\inf \{x_n:n\ge n_j\}\le x_{n_j}\le \sup\{x_{n}:n\ge n_j\}\text{ , }\forall j$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim\inf x_n\le\lim x_{n_k}\le \lim\sup x_n$$
So all convergent subsequence of $x_n$ converge to $\lim \sup x_n=\lim \inf x_n=x^*$, therefore $x_n$ converge to $x^*$

($\Rightarrow$)Let $x_n$ be a convergent sequence with limit $x^*$, then all subsequence of $x_n$ would converge to $x^*$, and the set of all subsequential limit is a singleton $\{x^*\}$. Note $\lim \sup x_n$ denotes the supremum of the set of subsequential limit and $\lim \inf x_n$ denotes the infimum of the set of subsequential limit, it follows that 
$$\lim \inf x_n=\lim \sup x_n=x^*$$

Answer (score 1):

The OP writes

> I try to assume $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}x_k-x_n\ge\epsilon$, how can I show the contradiction?

I see a sup inequality containing $k$, $n$, $x_k$, $x_n$ and $\varepsilon$ with no proof/argument context; it is confusing.

**The $\Rightarrow$ direction.**

If $x_n$ converges to $L$ then let any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ be given. We can find an $N$ such that $k \ge N$ implies $|x_k - L| \lt \varepsilon$. But then

$$\tag 1 L - \varepsilon \le \lim\inf x_n \le \lim\sup x_n \le L + \varepsilon$$

Since we can make $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily small, $\lim\inf x_n = \lim\sup x_n = L$.

**The $\Leftarrow$ direction.**

Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$ be given. We can find an $N$ such that when $k \ge N$,

$$\tag 2 \lim\inf x_n -  \varepsilon \le x_k \le \lim\sup x_n  + \varepsilon$$

For our setting, we can let $L$ denote the $\lim\inf x_n = \lim\inf x_n$ and write

$$\tag 3 L -  \varepsilon \le x_k \le L  + \varepsilon$$

But this is the same as saying that

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \,x_n= L$$